# Java stream of optionals to optional stream

Tags: java, functional-programming

I need to convert `Stream<Optional<Integer>>` to `Optional<Stream<Integer>>`.

The output `Optional<Stream<Integer>>` should be an empty value when at least one value of`Stream<Optional<Integer>>` is empty.

Do you know any functional way to solve the problem? I tried to use `collect` method, but without success.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this has already been answered yet to add to the list, with **Java-9** introducing [`Optional.stream`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--), this should be achievable as:

```
// initialized stream of optional
Stream<Optional<Integer>> so = Stream.empty(); 

// mapped stream of T 
Stream<Integer> s = so.flatMap(Optional::stream);   

// constructing optional from the stream
Optional<Stream<Integer>> os = Optional.of(s);
```

Comment: Not that my answer is particularly good either, but this doesn't solve the problem as-stated: that the `Stream<Optional<Integer>>` should be empty if any `Optional<Integer>` is empty. This answer just filters out the empty elements.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the tricky thing here is that if you're just given a `Stream`, you can only use it once.

To be stateless and avoid redundant copying, one way is to just catch `NoSuchElementException`:

```
static <T> Optional<Stream<T>> invert(Stream<Optional<T>> stream) {
    try {
        return Optional.of(
            stream.map(Optional::get)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList())
                  .stream());
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

A simple inversion would be:

```
static <T> Optional<Stream<T>> invert(Stream<Optional<T>> stream) {
    return Optional.of(stream.map(Optional::get));
}
```

But to find out if it contains an empty element, you need to actually traverse it which also consumes it.

If you're given the source of the stream, you can traverse it without collecting it:

```
static <T> Optional<Stream<T>> invert(
        Supplier<Stream<Optional<T>>> supplier) {
    // taking advantage of short-circuiting here
    // instead of allMatch(Optional::isPresent)
    return supplier.get().anyMatch(o -> !o.isPresent()) ?
        Optional.empty() : Optional.of(supplier.get().map(Optional::get));
}
```

```
List<Optional<Integer>> myInts =
    Arrays.asList(Optional.of(1), Optional.of(2), Optional.of(3));
Optional<Stream<Integer>> inverted = invert(myInts::stream);
```

That's probably a more interesting approach. (But it's prone to a race condition because the `stream()` is taken twice. If some other thread adds an empty element in between and gets away with it, we have a problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Radiodef's answer, though this one avoids the exception handling and the intermediate list.

```
private static <T> Optional<Stream<T>> invertOptional(Stream<Optional<T>> input) {
    return input.map(integer -> integer.map(Stream::of))
            .collect(Collectors.reducing((l, r) -> l.flatMap(lv -> r.map(rv -> Stream.concat(lv, rv)))))
            .orElse(Optional.empty());
}
```

The way this works is it maps to a Stream of Optional Streams of T.  The `Optional.map` is used in this case, so each one of the `Optional<Stream<T>>` items in the resultant stream is a either a Stream of 1, or an empty Optional.

Then it collects these streams by reducing them together. the `l.flatMap` will return an empty Optional if l is empty *or* the `r.map` returns an empty. if r.map isn't empty, it calls the Stream.concat, which combines the left and right stream values.

The whole collect reduction produces an `Optional<Optional<Stream<T>>>`, so we narrow that down with the `.orElse(Optional.empty)`

Note: Code is tested, and appears to work.  The unspecified "edge case" of an empty input Stream is treated as an an empty Optional, but can be easily changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    final Stream<Optional<Integer>> streamOfInts = Stream.of(Optional.of(1), Optional.of(2), Optional.of(3), Optional.of(4), Optional.of(5));

    // false - list of Optional.empty(); true -> list of Optional.of(Integer)
    final Map<Boolean, List<Optional<Integer>>> collect = streamOfInts.collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(Optional::isPresent));

    final Function<List<Optional<Integer>>, Stream<Integer>> mapToStream = List->List.stream().filter(o->o.isPresent()).map(o->o.get());

     Optional<Stream<Integer>> result = Optional
             .of(Optional.of(collect.get(false)).filter(list->list.size()>0).orElse(collect.get(true)))
             .filter(list->list.size()>0)
             .filter(list->list.get(0).isPresent())
             .map(mapToStream)
             .map(Optional::of)
             .orElse(Optional.empty());
```